# javascript, get script path from inside the script

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the Javascript server path?

For example, I have a javascript file that is in a directory, and in that directory there are some php scripts that I want to "post" to.

When I include the javascript file in my home page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/some.js"></script>
```

I can't access say a file like /post.php that resides in the assets/js/ directory using relative paths since the javascript is not being "run" in the directory that the home page is in.

Obviously, I can specify the path, but I was trying to think of a  more robust way.

I know you can get the "script" tags and get the url of the file, and I could probably work from there, but I didn't know if such a function exists, that would just tell you.

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't the basic problem with your code layout? Your javascript is not in a known location, making calling code in those directories hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a script that is served from bla.php and place it before your some.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bla.php"></script>
```

Inside bla.php, render a javascript class and store your data in it.
i.e.

```
function MyConstants() {
    this.HELLO = "hello";
    this.POST_PATH = "/etc.php";
}
```

You can access the constants (or anything else) via:

```
var consts = new MyConstants();
alert(consts.HELLO);
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: There is no point in making that a class.  Use an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a cross-browser [stack tracer](https://github.com/emwendelin/javascript-stacktrace) to get the current file name

however there are many cases where your idea this might break, For example if you add a JS cacher that complies all necessary JS files into one and compresses them.

I would say that a smarter approach is to have a principle in place with which you can figure out the urls for your php skripts, like RubyOnRails has [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)